# mongoose schema problem document can't store value of some filed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

here is my schema

```
let tbljobsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
companyid:{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
userid:{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,required:true,ref:'tblusers'},

jobtitle:{tyep:String,required:true},
category:{tyep:String,required:true},

skills:[{type:Number, default: []}],
salary:{type:Number, default: 0},
jobtype:{type:String, default: ''},
description:{type:String, default: ''},
description1:{type:String, default: ''},
createdon:{type:Date, default: Date.now()},
modifiedon:{type:Date,default: Date.now()},
});

const jobs = mongoose.model("tbljob",tbljobsSchema);
```

and here is my insert query

```
let newdata = new jobs({
userid:'5f4f6f6476bae31a70eca420',
skills:[4,4,4],
salary:15000,
jobtype:req.body.jobtype,
description:'test',
category:'test',
jobtitle:'test',
modifiedon:Date.now()
});

newdata.save();
```

but my document not showing `jobtitle` and `jobcategory` basically ti's not save

and if i am change name that fild then it's work fine

can you help what is happens with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both have typo's ,common mistake: (`tyep` to `type`)

```js
jobtitle:{tyep:String,required:true},
category:{tyep:String,required:true},
```

Change to ()

```js
jobtitle:{type:String,required:true},
category:{type:String,required:true},
```